How to fetch products by by parent tags?
I have the following tables:
// tags
+----+-----------------------+-----------+
| id |         name          | parent_id |
+----+-----------------------+-----------+
| 1  | Home                  | Null      |
| 2  | Kitchen               | 1         |
| 3  | Serving and reception | 2         |
| 4  | Spoon                 | 3         |
| 5  | Digital               | NULL      |
| 6  | Communication         | 5         |
| 7  | Cellphone             | 6         |
+----+-----------------------+-----------+

// products
+----+------------------------------------------+--------+
| id |                name                      | tag_id | -- this is the deepest tag id
+----+------------------------------------------+--------+
| 1  | Dinner Spoon Set,16 Pcs 7.3" Tablespoons | 4      | 
| 2  | iPhone 14 Promax                         | 7      |
+----+------------------------------------------+--------+

I need to implement a listing page per "tag". So, I need to get "iPhone 14 Promax" by each of the following tags.ids: 5, 6, 7 (since they are all related to that product)
Any idea by what query can I get product#2 (iPhone 14 Promax) by having tag#6 (Communication)?

Noted that, I can get product#2 by having  tag#7 by a simple join:
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
JOIN tags t 
  ON t.id = p.tag_id
WHERE t.id = 7

But I don't know how can I get the product by higher level tag ids.

What version of MySQL are you using?

@TimBiegeleisen MySQL ver 8.0.37

On MySQL 8+, we can use a recursive CTE:
WITH RECURSIVE cte (id, name, parent_id, orig_id) AS (
    SELECT id, name, parent_id, id AS orig_id
    FROM tags
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.parent_id, t2.orig_id
    FROM tags t1
    INNER JOIN cte t2
        ON t2.id = t1.parent_id
)

SELECT MAX(p.name) AS name
FROM cte t
LEFT JOIN products p
    ON p.tag_id = t.id
GROUP BY t.orig_id
HAVING SUM(t.id = 6) > 0;

Demo
The strategy here is to start the recursive CTE at the top of each product hierarchy, which means the records having no (NULL) parents.  Note that we pass down the original parent id value as we recurse.  This means that we can figure out which products in the hierarchy belong to the same group.
We then join to the products table, to bring in the name, and we aggregate by the orig_id group.  A match is a hierarchy having the desired id, somewhere along the chain.

It doesn't work and returns null. Though when I replace 6 with 7, it returns   "iPhone 14 Promax" as well

I have edited my answer several times.  Can you reload your page and make sure you are using the latest version?

You know, the logic is correct, it knows there is one product that should be selected, but it returns NULL instead of the name of the product ("iPhone 14 Promax")

I mean, when I put 60000 instead of 6, it returns nothing (no result, no row),  but now, it returns one row (as expected) but NULL value for the name

Check the edit, I fixed it.

Your query is great, just has a minor issue, it always returns one row. I added a new product "Samsung Galaxy A55", and your query switched to the new defined product and ignored "iPhone 14 Promax", while they both must be selected. https://dbfiddle.uk/zn353A_W

If you can live with getting a CSV output of all matching products, then just select GROUP_CONCAT(p.name) in the final query, q.v. the updated demo here: https://dbfiddle.uk/2x7ebC04
